# React testing library differences between clicks using userEvent, fireEvent and regular clicks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

In the course of learning TDD with React, I noticed that there are different ways to trigger a click on an element in the test. It can be done through `fireEvent.click()`, `userEvent.click()` and  `HTML_ELEMENT.click()`.

They all work fine. After doing some research, I understood that `userEvent.click()` basically uses fireEvent under the hood, and it is preferable for automated tests (e.g. cypress), while the `fireEvent.click()` is more preferable in unit tests.

But I could not find what both `userEvent` and `fireEvent` differ from the regular `HTML_ELEMENT.click()` function that can be used.

What benefits do I gain from using them instead of using the regular click function?

Answer (score 4):

I think the `fireEvent.click()` only emits `onClick` which on the other hand `userEvent.click()` emits all sort of events which when user `clicks` will happen.

here is one of the functions which will trigger when a labeled is clicked:

```
function clickLabel(label, init, {clickCount}) {
  if (isLabelWithInternallyDisabledControl(label)) return

  fireEvent.pointerDown(label, init)
  fireEvent.mouseDown(
    label,
    getMouseEventOptions('mousedown', init, clickCount),
  )
  fireEvent.pointerUp(label, init)
  fireEvent.mouseUp(label, getMouseEventOptions('mouseup', init, clickCount))
  fireEvent.click(label, getMouseEventOptions('click', init, clickCount))
  // clicking the label will trigger a click of the label.control
  // however, it will not focus the label.control so we have to do it
  // ourselves.
  if (label.control) focus(label.control)
}
```

so in a nutshell `fireEvent.click` is one the steps that are used in `userEvent.click` and there are more steps

you can read the source code here: https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/master/src/click.js

here are some more code from source code which will happen on `userEvent.click`

```
function clickElement(element, init, {clickCount}) {
  const previousElement = getPreviouslyFocusedElement(element)
  fireEvent.pointerDown(element, init)
  if (!element.disabled) {
    const continueDefaultHandling = fireEvent.mouseDown(
      element,
      getMouseEventOptions('mousedown', init, clickCount),
    )
    if (
      continueDefaultHandling &&
      element !== element.ownerDocument.activeElement
    ) {
      if (previousElement && !isFocusable(element)) {
        blur(previousElement, init)
      } else {
        focus(element, init)
      }
    }
  }
  fireEvent.pointerUp(element, init)
  if (!element.disabled) {
    fireEvent.mouseUp(
      element,
      getMouseEventOptions('mouseup', init, clickCount),
    )
    fireEvent.click(element, getMouseEventOptions('click', init, clickCount))
    const parentLabel = element.closest('label')
    if (parentLabel?.control) focus(parentLabel.control, init)
  }
}
```

Comment: But what do these two differ from the regular click() function

Comment: @ZaidShawahin the differences are that you get more `events` that are fired when you use `userEvent.click` and that's closer to what happens when a user clicks. for example if you have an `eventListener` on `mouseDown` that won't be trigger when you use `fireEvent.click` but it will trigger when you use `userEvent.click`

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my question, thank you for explaining the difference between `fireEvent` and `userEvent`, but it remains unclear what is the difference between using them two or using the regular HTML element click function?

Comment: I came here curious about your original question, how does HTML_ELEMENT.click() differ, under the hood it appears that there is no difference. I could be wrong, but if you wander through fireEvent code inside of @testing-library/dom (events.js), it looks like it's doing key value lookups with the method supplied. I think from a coding practice standpoint, it is useful to have consistency but yea, this is a bit of a head scratch-er to me, I can't find any real difference between fireEvent[event] and HTML_Element[event] (user event is naturally a different story as Taghi pointed out).

Comment: came here regarding the same pointed out by @AndrogenAgonist... **why** should i use `fireEvent.click()` (or `userEvent`) instead of just `element.click()`. I *think* (not sure) can have something to do with wrapping the interaction inside `act()`; `fireEvent.click()` does already wrap inside `act()` BUT not sure if there is any other reason.